# Trying to get previous day date but facing error: unknown group operator '$gte'

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
db.system.js.insertOne(
   {
   _id : "getPreviousDayDates" ,
     value : function (){ return db.Smx_20213_ShiftOEEDaily.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
         _id: "$machineName",
         maxlogdate: { $max: "$logDate" }
         }
     }
   ]
   ); }
   }
);

db.eval("getPreviousDayDates()")
```

//Getting Current Date from this collection, but I wants to get previous day, So firstly I am getting current date from maxlogdate and now I wants to take previous date so, that's why I wrote this query but facing the issue as: unknown group operator '$gte'

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do. Are you trying to insert another document with the same _id? Do you expect to have documents with this _id already on the db?

Comment: @nimrodserok  Here, I am trying to get previous date and grouping that date by machine name. and the maxlogdate is for getting the maximum date from the table so that I can get current date. So now I wants to subtract the maxlogdate -1 so that I will get previous date i.e. (Previous_date= maxlogdate-1) Basically I wants to perform this operation. Can you help me with it ?

Comment: I can help you, but I need to understand what are you trying to do. I can read the query, but this does not explain it to me. Please provide some sample data, 3 documents to put in a db, the document that you are trying to insert and the expected outcome

Comment: @nimrodserok I have edited the code. So basically, in this function I wants add one more field that is previous date. I am getting current date from "maxlogdate". I need to get previous date from this function. So how can I get the previous date from maxlogdate field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a new document, that contains a field that is retrieved from existing documents, you can use an aggregation pipeline with a `$merge` step:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {machineName: "a"}},
  {$group: {_id: 0, timestamp: {$max: "$timestamp"}}},
  {$addFields: {data: newObjectToInsert}},
  {$set: {"data.previousDate": "$timestamp"}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}},
  {$merge: {into: "collection"}}
])
```

As you can see on this [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FehYEL6hHUH).

First we `$match` all the documents with the same `machineName`. Then we `$sort` them according to the timestamp, and `$limit` to one, in order to have just the last value. Now we need to add our `newObjectToInsert`, `$set` the new field and `$merge` to insert to the collection.

If you want to subtract one day from the date, you can use:

```
{
    $set: {"data.previousDate": {
        $dateAdd: {
          startDate: "$timestamp",
          unit: "day",
          amount: -1
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

instead of:

```
{$set: {"data.previousDate": "$timestamp"}},
```

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: No it's still giving me an error as ReferenceError: newObjectToInsert is not defined :

Comment: You need to replace this with the object you want to insert to the db.

Comment: See the playground example link in the answer.

Comment: Is it working for you?